# using pointers to arrays in a function

Tags: c++

I have declared a 2_D array as

```
int array [NO_OF_ROWS][NO_OF_COL];
```

`NO_OF_ROWS` and `NO_OF_COL` are constants.

I then have pointers `*rowPtr` and `*seatPtr`.  I pass all of these to a function so I can save data from a binary file to the array along with an enumerated status as follows

```
 void loadArray (int* &rowPtr, int* &seatPtr, status& seatStatus,
               status seatArray[][NO_OF_COL])
```

in the function i try to save the status to the array with the line;

```
 seatArray[rowPtr][seatPtr] = seatStatus;
```

when I try to compile I get the error:

> invalid types ' status(*)[6][int*] for array subscript

I see that the array does not like the pointer value since it was declared as an int type. How would I set this up to allow the pointer to be used

Comment: Why write any of this nonsense instead of using C++? Use `std::array` or `std::vector`, and don't use pointers.

Comment: Forget everything you know. Learn C++. ^^ . Also 2D arrays are bad. You can do just fine with one array and smart indexing. In addition it *may*  be faster since you only have one level of indirection - if you care about these things anyway..

Comment: @KerrekSB Why do you always say people should use STL containers. Their flexibility comes with some price also. You do need to be more careful with pointers, but you've also get a lot in reward.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what `rowPtr` and `seatPtr` are supposed to represent. Could you post the code-snippet that initializes them?

Comment: @FailedDev I've seen a lot of experienced developers here, who after seeing pointers immediately say that STL string or vector should be used. But those are slower and have bigger memory footprint. Shouldn't this also considered?

Comment: @RomanB. Well, I used to work in embedded systems. So in those cases where memory is 2Kbyte etc. yes. They are also faster. But in 90% of scenarios, plus in 99% of the questions here these *benefits* are insignificant.

Comment: @FailedDev That's right, but people here start learning.. And all we say to them, take string and you do not need to know what is char*. Well, we could say, forget everything and learn Java.

Comment: @RomanB.: Take it for what it's worth. Basically, you can ignore the advice once you understand why you can ignore it. If you have to post on SO because you're confused, chances are the advice applies, though. Also, `std::array` doesn't come at any price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the pointers incorrectly.  Try this:

```
void loadArray (int* rowPtr, int* seatPtr, status& seatStatus,
           status seatArray[][NO_OF_COL])
```

And then dereference the pointers when you want to use their values as such:

```
seatArray[*rowPtr][*seatPtr] = seatStatus;
```

Comment: I really doubt the OP understood what you did, or learned anything at all. But +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Dereference the pointers.

```
seatArray[*rowPtr][*seatPtr] = seatStatus;
```